# Running a DFT Based on a condition in SSIS

Tags: ssis, msbi

I've a package where I need to retrieve data from a mysql table and insert it into sql server table.
I've a situation where in old data often gets modified and the client wants to dump all data which is too large and time consuming...So I've come up with a proposal that we'd load only yesterday's data on week days and do complete dump on weekend...Is there a possibility of Enable/Disabling a DFT Based on an expression? I've Tried using Expressions->Disable based on DATEPART(WeekDAY,GETDATE()) but it runs for a complete load irrespective of expression's value

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a SQL Task or Script Task that does your expression, and set the result to a variable. 
Then create your data flow task. 
Then connect the two with an arrow (aka precedence constraint)

Then right-click:Edit on the arror and choose Edit, and in the Precedence Constraint Editor choose 
   EvaluationOperation: Expression
   Value:  @@YourVariable= {an expression, such as @iRowsUpdated==True}

Answer (score 0):

You should put the condition as a where clause against your select statement in your source query.  You will need to change access mode from table to SQL Statement first